# Using UIPageViewController in Swift with "as" downcast

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a PageViewController, and then I declared the Data Source for the PageViewController, and when implementing the required methods I get an error when using the as downcast it says "correctViewController is not a type."

```
import UIKit

class HarishPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

let pageTitles = ["HarishIntroduction", "HarishPlaces", "WyomingSeminary", "AppleTree", "KearneyHighSchool", "MosconeCenter"]
let viewControllerArray: NSArray = [HarishIntroduction(), HarishPlaces(), WyomingSeminary(), AppleTree(), KearneyHighSchool(), MosconeCenter()]
var index = 0

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if index == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    else {
        index--
        let page = pageTitles[index]
        let correctViewController: UIViewController = viewControllerArray[index] as! UIViewController
        let vc = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(page) as correctViewController

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

[image: Ignore the error next to the class that should disappear once I include all of the required methods.]

I have tried many different ways, but I am just not able to get rid of the error next to the as. Any ideas?

Comment: you are missing the `viewControllerAfterViewController` and as the compiler correctly states `correctViewController` is not a type, but a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a type or a class. You are trying to downcast to a variable.

After  `as` just write the class of your controller

Comment: Oh ok, so I will just write the class of the controller.

Comment: Also consider mentioning the issue of non-conformence w.r.t. protocol UIPageViewControllerDataSource, or the posters code will still display compile time errors.

Comment: @dfri How else could I right the code with the as statement because when I use `instantiateViewController` method I have to use as and then the viewController type. Since I have multiple viewControllers I can't just right the name of one view controller. How else could I do it without just writing the name of the viewController.

Comment: @Harish As Alessandro writes, you cannot downcast to a variable; you downcast to a **type**. I would presume the immutable string property `page` controls which of your multiple viewcontrollers you are trying access.

Comment: Ok, I will try to implement that.